# Reading/Writing to and from a file using the path

Tags: python, path, concatenation

How do I go about reading from or writing to a file that isn't in the same folder as the file itself.

I'm trying to write a function that allows user input to find the file by using the path itself. I have to set it up where the user inputs the file name, then the path

I have to then concatenate them together to form the finished path to locate the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to construct file paths from distinct parts:

```
import os.path

dirname = '/foo/bar/baz'
filename = 'ham_n_spam'
path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
```

Comment: How would I do it so the user could put the path themselves? Would it be: dirname = input()
filename = input()
path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)?

Comment: @JustinFarr: Why don't you try that out? What happens when you do that?

Comment: I tried it out but I don't know how to call it.

import os.path
dirname = input()
filename = input()
path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
read = open(path, "r")

def read_file():
    path = input("Enter the path that contains the file: ")
    file1 = input("Enter the file name to open: ")
    with open(file1, "r") as x:
        return x.readlines()

So it's telling me the directory or file doesn't exist. I'm just trying to figure out how to implement it with my function. I'm sorry for how jumbled this all is

Comment: @JustinFarr: so `file1` is not a valid path. Try thinking about what I told you and how that applies to the `file1` and `path` variables in your `read_file()` function.

Comment: So I would have to change the 'file1' into the 'filename' variable so it would be a valid path?

Comment: @JustinFarr: what do you think happens then? I have the impression you wanted to use `os.path.join()` on `path` and `file1` instead, producing a full path to pass to `open()`.

Comment: I'm assuming it takes my input and joins it with my dirname input to make my path which then I could use in my `with open(path, "r") as x:` code but it keeps coming back with the error "read = open(path, "r") TypeError: invalid file: ()

Comment: @JustinFarr: you are passing in a *tuple* instead of a string. `path` is not the output of `os.path.join(path, file1)` in that case.

Comment: I'm confused now by what you said. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @JustinFarr: your error message shows that the variable `path` is bound to the empty tuple `()`. That's not a valid filename. *How you got there* I don't know. Perhaps you need to ask a new question about that. Show the code that produces the error, plus the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Well, I've fixed that issue. My current issue at hand is `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Justin\\Desktop'`

Comment: @JustinFarr: hrm, Python 3  gives you a specific error for directories on Mac; it *could* be you are trying to read the directory `C:\Users\Justin\Desktop` rather than a file `C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\some_file.txt`; I have no Windows machines around to test.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure it out completely before my 12am deadline to turn it in. Thank you very much for helping me as much as you were able to.